# Topology question sequence convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology, convergence-divergence

A subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is open if it is either $\mathbb{R}$, $\emptyset$, or an interval of the form $(a,\infty)$ where $a$ is any real number.

(a) Show that with the above topology the sequence

$(1,2,3,4,5, ...)$ converges to every point on $\mathbb{R}$.

(b) Give a sequence which, with the above topology, does not converge to any point in $\mathbb{R}$ at all.

I guess for (a) I need to show that it converges for an arbitrary point, but I'm not quite sure how to structure it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Choose any $x\in\Bbb R$ and structure the proof it as a verification of the defining property of convergence to $x$.

Comment: Hint: What is your definition of converges to a point?  It's different from the version in calculus.

Comment: Further hint: Once you figure out (a), you'll see how to do (b) immediately.

Comment: I've got the definition in front of me but I'm just not sure how it applies in this case with the intervals. How exactly would you right down the topology described above anyway? @MichaelBurr

Comment: Is this your definition of convergence? $(x_n:n∈\mathbb{N})$ converges to $x$ if and only if for each open nbhd $U$ of $x$ there is an $m∈\mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n∈U$ whenever $n≥m_U$.

Comment: You have already written down the topology, by describing its elements with complete precision. It's elements are: the subset $\mathbb R$; the subset $\emptyset$; and all of the subsets $(a,\infty)$, for $a \in \mathbb R$.

Comment: My definition is similar but not the same. For a sequence $(x_n)_n$ $\subseteq$ $X$ converges to $Y \in X$ if for all open $U \in X$ that contain $y$, $\exists$ $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_n \in U$ $ \forall n \ge N$.

Comment: But I still don't see how I can use this to show that $(1,2,3,4,5,...)$ converges to an arbitrary point say $y \in \mathbb{R}$???

Comment: fix any $x \in \mathbb{R}$. The open neightbourhoods containing $x$ are $\mathbb{R}$ itself and all open intervals of the form $(a,\infty)$, for $a \leq x$.It should now be clear what you should do. For (2) choose a sequence that goes to $-\infty$, and for that sequence the condition is violated so doesn't converge to any point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that for a topological space $X$, a sequence $x_n$ converges to a point $x\in X$ if for every neighborhood $U$ of $x$ there exists $N$ such that $n\geqslant N$ implies $x_n\in U$.

Let $x_n=n$ be the sequence given in part a). $x\in\mathbb R$ and $U$ a neighborhood of $x$. Then $U$ contains an interval of the form $(a,\infty)$ with $x\in (a,\infty)$; in other words $a<x<\infty$. Choose $N$ such that $N>a$. Then for $n\geqslant N$ we have $x_n=n>a$, so that $x_n\in(a,\infty)\subset U$. It follows that $x_n$ converges to $x$.

For b), consider the sequence $x_n=-n$. Then for any $x\in\mathbb R$, let $a=\lfloor x\rfloor-1$ be one less than the greatest integer not exceeding $x$. Let $U=(a,\infty)$, then $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$. But $a$ is the smallest integer in $U$, so there exists $N$ such that $-N<a$, hence $-N\notin U$. It follows that $x_n$ does not converge to $x$.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Take $y \in \mathbb{R}$. Put $x_n := n, n \geq 1$. We show that $x_n \to y$.

Let $U$ be open in $X$ containing $y$. The case $U = \mathbb{R}$ is dealt with trivially, so we may assume $U$ is of the form

$$U= (a,  + \infty)$$ where $a< y < + \infty$.

Let $N$ be any integer strictly greater than $a$. Then for $n \geq N$, we have $x_n = n \geq N > a$ and thus $x_n \in U$ for $n \geq N$.

(2) Given the topology, it should be clear that

$$-1,-2,-3, \dots$$

does never converge.

Indeed, let $x$ be a limit candidate for the sequence. Consider the open set $(x-1,+ \infty)$. Eventually, the sequence will leave this set.

Answer (score 1):

> $(x_n)$ converges to $x$ iff for every open set $O$ that contains $x$, there is some $N \in \Bbb N$ such that for all $n \ge N$ we have $x_n \in O$.

So let $x$ be any real number and let $O=(a,\infty)$ be an open set containing $x$, which just means that $a < x (\le |x|)$. (we don't need to consider $O=\Bbb R$ because then we can just take $N=1$ trivially, and this is the only other type of open set that can contain $x$).

Now, if $N$ is chosen so that $N > |x|$, which is always possible as |x| is just some finite value, then $n \ge N$ implies $x_n = n \ge N > |x| \ge x > a$ so that $x_n \in O$ for all $n \ge N$.

As $x$ and $)$ are arbitrary the definition just says that $x_n \to x$ as required.

Now note that $x_n = -n$ does *not* converge to any point as any open set of the form $(a,\infty)$ only contains at most finitely many $x_n$.